# Magento 2.2 Override Sales Invoice attachment files

Tags: magento2.2, overrides, invoice, order-email, attachment

We need to override following files in custom module.

```
/data/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php
/data/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
/data/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/AbstractItems.php
/data/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php
```

We've tried many different ways but that didn't work. So Please help me the proper ways to override vendor files in App/Code. Magento 2.2

Comment: so do you have final solution? can you share your experience how did you get it done finally?Thanks

Comment: Check my answer. Someone gave me di.xml example So based on that I created new Module and Following are XML which I created.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try Following methods in di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="ExtensionName\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" type="ExtensionName\Modulename\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf"/>
</config>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Fooman\EmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceObserver" type="Myvendorfolder\EmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceObserver" />
        <virtualType name="myvendorfolder_emailattachments_invoice_pdf_renderer" type="\Myvendorfolder\EmailAttachments\Model\PdfRenderer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
        <type name="\Myvendorfolder\EmailAttachments\Observer\AbstractSendInvoiceObserver">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="pdfRenderer" xsi:type="object">myvendorfolder_emailattachments_invoice_pdf_renderer</argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
    </config>
```

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
        /**
        * @author     Kristof Ringleff
        * @package    Fooman_EmailAttachments
        * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015 Fooman Limited (http://www.fooman.co.nz)
        *
        * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
        * file that was distributed with this source code.
        */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <!--Invoice Emails-->
        <event name="myvendorfolder_emailattachments_before_send_invoice">
            <observer name="myvendorfolder_emailattachments_before_send_invoice_observer"
                      instance="Myvendorfolder\EmailAttachments\Observer\BeforeSendInvoiceObserver"/>
        </event>
    </config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Myvendorfolder_EmailAttachments" setup_version="2.1.0">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Fooman_EmailAttachments"/>
            </sequence>
        </module>
    </config>
```

Comment: worked for me , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Below Method in Your Module di.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf" type="Your_ExtensionName/Your_ModuleName/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf" />
<preference for="vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice" type="Your_ExtensionName/Your_ModuleName/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice" />
<preference for="vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/AbstractItems" type="Your_ExtensionName/Your_MOduleName/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/AbstractItems" />
<preference for="vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice" type="Your_ExtensionName/Your_MOduleName/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice" />
</config>
```

Comment: Your written code is not perfect.